# installation of .run file /// check dependencies fail

Tags: command-line, apt, system-installation, software-installation, supervisor

****im trying to install a .run file in ubuntu 20.04
but i keep getting check dependencies fail, check below****

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

```
sudo./irzlink.run

Creating directory /opt/link

Verifying archive integrity...
100%   MD5 checksums are OK. All good.

Uncompressing iRZ Link Managment System  100%  

# check dependences...

mongodb-server      [v3+]       [OK]
nginx               [v1+]       [OK]
supervisor          [v3+]       [FAILED]
python              [v3.5+]     [OK]
python-pip          [v10+]      [OK]

!!! Resolve dependences and try again.
```

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

**the wierd thing that is supervisor is installed and the service is runinning. i can access the web client of the supervisor and checked**

using

```
lsof -i tcp | grep LISTEN
```

**supervisor is listenning to the port, im out of solutions
kindly, help**

Comment: There is no Ubuntu version 20. Are you running 20.10 or 20.04?

Comment: my mistake 20.04

Comment: "the wierd thing that is supervisor is installed and the service is runinning." but that is only 1/2 of what is asked ...is it v3.5+?

Comment: yes supervisord -v
4.1.0

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Comment: atcually im very disspointed, everybody is looking to show misktakes in my question, no one is trying to help.